# sftp chroot access via SSH

Tags: ssh, chroot

I have this setup in sshd_config:

```
AllowUsers test1 test2

Match group sftpgroup
         ChrootDirectory /var/www
         X11Forwarding no
         AllowTcpForwarding no
         ForceCommand internal-sftp

Match user test2
         ChrootDirectory /var/www/somedomain.dk
         X11Forwarding no
         AllowTcpForwarding no
         ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I am trying to restrict **test2** to only use **/var/www/somedomain.dk**

For some reason when I try to login e.g. with Filezilla on account **test2** I get this error: "**Server unexpectedly closed network connection**"

The users are created and works. the SSH service has been stopped and started. **test1** works when using e.g. filezilla and the root of the connection is **/var/www**. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the answer Cudos supplied does not help you, and I dont think it will (no offense), try this:

```
chown root:root /your/chroot/home
chmod 700 /your/chroot/home
chown user:sftpgroup /your/chroot/home/userdir
chmod 755 /your/chroot/home/userdir
```

remember: your users wont be able to write in their "root", you need to create a directory for them to use.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for bringing this feature of SSH to my attention.

The following Debian Administration article states that the target directory must be owned by root - perhaps /var/www/somedomain.dk is not.

http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/590

Comment: yeah, thanks for showing me too. this kind of config for sftp is new to me also...  "Specifying a command of ``internal-sftp'' will force the use of an in-process sftp server that requires no support files when used with  ChrootDirectory."